# Match lines with a range of time values

Tags: php, regex

I have an array that exposed the output from a rooter cisco command `show ip bgp summary`; this command show the used/active/idle/etc. connexion at bgp connection.

The array looks like:

```
[router_name] =>
8.8.8.8    4 54332       0       0        0    0    0 never    Active
4.4.4.4     4 14432       0       0        0    0    0 never    Active
1.1.1.1  4 53222       0       0        0    0    0 never    Active
3.2.54.3   4 64323    9743    9236        0    0    0 3d14h    Idle (Admin)
60.34.22.56  4 99999    8434    9214        0    0    0 3d14h    Idle (Admin)
43.22.55.3   4 66789    5057    4980        0    0    0 03:30:00    Idle (Admin)
```

I want to show in the array ID (`router_name`) just the line containing `03:30:00`, and if it is smaller than 6 hours, I want to delete the rest from the array.

The code in my php is like this:

```
$bgp_routers = "/path/to/a/file/that/contains/the/router/list";

$routers_list = array_filter(explode("\n",file_get_contents($bgp_routers)),'strlen');


foreach ($routers_list as $k=>$v) {
    $bgp_out[$v]=array_filter(explode('#',shell_exec("$bgp_expect $v")),'strlen');
    $bgp_out[$v] = $bgp_out[$v][2];
}

foreach ($bgp_out as $k=>$v){
    $bgp_out2[$k] = array_filter(explode("\n",preg_replace(array('/sh ip b s \| i Active\|Idle/'),'',$v)),'strlen');
    array_pop($bgp_out2[$k]);
    unset($bgp_out2[$k][0]);
}
foreach ($bgp_out2 as $k=>$v){
    $count = count($v);
    for ($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++) { $bgp1[$k][$i] = (preg_match('/(\s+|.*):(\s+|.*)/',$v[$i])) ? $v[$i] : '';  }
}
```

And the output for:

$bgp_out:

```
Array
(
    [Router_name3] => sh ip b s | i Active|Idle
332.11.1.110    4 12341       0       0        0    0    0 never    Idle (Admin)
332.11.1.114    4 12341       0       0        0    0    0 never    Idle (Admin)
332.11.1.118    4 12341       0       0        0    0    0 never    Idle (Admin)
Router_name3
    [Router_name4] => sh ip b s | i Active|Idle
332.11.0.106    4 423432       0       0        0    0    0 03:01:21    Active
332.11.2.22     4 42322       0       0        0    0    0 never    Active
332.11.13.238   4 5243       0       0        0    0    0 never    Active
2.11.218.82   4 2222    9743    9236        0    0    0 3d14h    Idle (Admin)
2.11.218.117  4 23423    8434    9214        0    0    0 3d14h    Idle (Admin)
190.86.127.121   4 234    5057    4980        0    0    0 00:01:00    Idle (Admin)
94.177.37.165   4 423423    4521    5015        0    0    0 3d14h    Idle (Admin)
178.21.121.73   4 423432   27364   26346        0    0    0 3d14h    Idle (Admin)
Router_name4
    [router_name1] => sh ip b s | i Active|Idle
332.11.10.78    4 42343   13851   81070        0    0    0 1y8w     Active
332.11.11.18    4 75675       0       0        0    0    0 never    Active
332.11.12.178   4 76576       0       0        0    0    0 never    Idle (Admin)
332.11.13.150   4 65756       0  282570        0    0    0 never    08:00:00
router_name1
    [Router_name2] => sh ip b s | i Active|Idle
332.11.0.114    4  5675 1194812  416375        0    0    0 2w0d     Active
2.11.218.1    4  45666 3663159 5094548        0    0    0 1w0d     Active
Router_name2
)
```

$bgp_out2:

```
Array
(
    [router_name3] => Array
        (
            [1] => 324.32.1.110    4 34522       0       0        0    0    0 never    Idle (Admin)
            [2] => 324.32.1.114    4 34522       0       0        0    0    0 never    Idle (Admin)
            [3] => 324.32.1.118    4 34522       0       0        0    0    0 never    Idle (Admin)
        )

    [router_name4] => Array
        (
            [1] => 324.32.0.106    4 42343       0       0        0    0    0 03:01:21    Active
            [2] => 324.32.2.22     4 24234       0       0        0    0    0 never    Active
            [3] => 324.32.13.238   4 32432       0       0        0    0    0 never    Active
            [4] => 12.324.218.82   4 42332    9743    9236        0    0    0 3d15h    Idle (Admin)
            [5] => 12.324.218.117  4 12312    8434    9214        0    0    0 3d15h    Idle (Admin)
            [6] => 3.86.127.121   4 12444    5057    4980        0    0    0 00:01:00    Idle (Admin)
            [7] => 94.17.37.165   4 39737    4521    5015        0    0    0 3d15h    Idle (Admin)
            [8] => 18.21.121.73   4 14124   27364   26346        0    0    0 3d15h    Idle (Admin)
        )

    [router_name1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 324.32.10.78    4 39335   13851   81070        0    0    0 1y8w     Active
            [2] => 324.32.11.18    4 34732       0       0        0    0    0 never    Active
            [3] => 324.32.12.178   4 43890       0       0        0    0    0 8:00:00    Idle (Admin)
            [4] => 324.32.13.150   4 34279       0  283414        0    0    0 never    Idle
        )

    [router_name2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 324.32.0.114    4  5483 1194812  416375        0    0    0 2w0d     Active
            [2] => 12.324.218.1    4  3234 3663159 5094548        0    0    0 1w0d     Active
        )

)
```

Expected output:

```
array (
[router_name4] => 
array( 
[0] => 324.32.0.106    4 42343       0       0        0    0    0 03:01:21    Active 
[1] => 3.86.127.121   4 12444    5057    4980        0    0    0 00:01:00
)
)
```

Any solution?

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: I have added to the question.

Comment: So, if there's at least one line with idle < 6hr, you want to only show that line ... and if not, show everything?

Comment: Yes but that line maybe the first or second, you got the point :P

Comment: Perhaps you could give the expected output for what you have mentioned and also for the scenario in which there are no lines that match the < 6hrs.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  What happened when you tried it?  What did you get and what were you expecting?

Comment: I have added all of my code and the output from it.

Comment: @Cosmin You should also add the *expected* output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would match a line with a time less than 6 hours:

```
preg_match_all('/^.*0[0-5]:\d{2}:\d{2}.*$/m', $str, $matches);
```

For each line it matches a `hh:mm:ss` pattern of which the hour component is between `0` and `5` inclusive.

The `$matches` array contains the lines that matched, or is empty if none of the lines matched.